# How to fix ''required' initializer must be accessible wherever class 'BeAlertController' can be subclassed'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podspec

I'm trying to open my sub-class, so that it can be accessible outside of module. Its being compiled successfully in xCode but failed when i run `pod spec lint mypodname.podspec`

Previous version of my class is public and its working fine, now i want to change the class to open. I have implemented `public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` method as well.
Everything works fine in xCode but not when i hit `pod spec lint`

```
open class BeAlertController: UIViewController

public init(title: String?, message: String?) 

public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

setupViews()
}
```

It should build successfully as in xCode.If you want to try you can have a clone
[CustomAlertController](https://github.com/shahbazsaleem01/CustomAlertController)

Comment: Make `init?(coder:)` be `open` instead of `public`?

Comment: Got error: 
Only classes and overridable class members can be declared 'open'; use 'public'

Comment: Well I guess you’ve hit a bug in lint.

Comment: what kinda bug, previous version of pod is running fine,

Comment: you can clone if you want a deep look, i have updated my question